# casting void pointers

Tags: c, malloc

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)
>   [Should I explicitly cast malloc()'s return value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953112/should-i-explicitly-cast-mallocs-return-value)

Hello,

gcc 4.4.4 c89

Normally I don't cast the return result from a malloc call.

```
int *int_ptr = NULL;
int_ptr = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

However, I have read on here, that if you cast it can hide errors. How does it hide errors if you explicitly cast to an int?

```
int_ptr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

Also, I was reading a c programming book that stated it was good programming practice to cast from a void pointer including a call from malloc.

Which would be good programming practice?

```
int *int_ptr = NULL;
void *ptr = NULL;

int_ptr = ptr;
```

or

```
int_ptr = (int*)ptr;
```

Many thanks for any advice,

Comment: Duplicate? There are [many](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565496/specifically-whats-dangerous-about-casting-the-result-of-malloc) [very](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/953112/should-i-explicitly-cast-mallocs-return-value) [similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108768/needless-pointer-casts-in-c) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How does it hide errors if you
>   explicitly cast to an int?

It can hide the error of neglecting to include `stdlib.h` before you call `malloc`.  Without the proper function declaration, the C compiler can assume that it returns an `int`, and an explicit cast will mask the fact that you're not calling `malloc` properly.  See [Q7.6](http://www.c-faq.com/malloc/decl.html) and [Q7.16](http://www.c-faq.com/malloc/sizetlong.html) from the comp.lang.c FAQ.

> Also, I was reading a c programming
>   book that stated it was good
>   programming practice to cast from a
>   void pointer including a call from
>   malloc.
>
> Which would be good programming
>   practice?

There is no point to explicitly casting the result of `malloc` in C.  It potentially masks errors, and it increases the maintenance burden (if you ever decide to change the allocated type, you now have an extra site in the code that must be altered).

The only time you should perform an explicit cast from `void*` so is if you will be compiling your code as C++ since C++ does not allow that as an implicit cast. (But if you are writing C++ code, you should be using `static_cast` in this case.)

Comment: question is: should you use malloc at all when coding in C++ (but I guess that's been discussed myriads of times before)

Comment: @msiemeri: Generally it should be avoided, but if you're interfacing with existing C code, that's not always an option.

Answer (score 1):

Don't cast the `void*` return value of `malloc()` unless it is to make GCC be quiet in your environment, or if it is mandated by co-workers, etc...

Cast or no cast, `void*` is only a memory address. Assigning it to a variable with a type gives it meaning, and avoiding the cast makes code easier to read.

Comment: What is this `NULL*` thing of which you speak?  You must mean `void*`.

Comment: Hahahaha....my haste made a mess of my post. Thanks, that is silly.